# CSS Layout Fixed-Width

Tags: css, browser, layout, fixed-width

I am aiming for a fixed width layout, with `width:1008px` across all monitors. Here's my HTML-

```
<body>
<div id="god_container">
    <div id="root">
        ... all content ...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and CSS -

```
#god_container{                                                                                                       
    background:url("/site_media/images/bg-1008.png") repeat-y scroll center center #D4D9DD;                           
    margin:auto;                                                                                                      
    position:static;                                                                                                  
    width:auto;                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                     

#root {                                                                                                               
    background-color:#FFFFFF;                                                                                         
    margin:auto;                                                                                                      
    width:1008px;                                                                                                     
    color:#000000;                                                                                                    
    font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;                                                                             
    font-size:10pt;                                                                                                   
}
body{
    color:#373737;
    font:16px arial;
    line-height:1;
    background-color:#D4D9DD;
}
```

I thought this would solve it. But when I render, the `root` css does not adhere to `1008px` value. Also root's `background-color` does not show as `#FFFFFF` i.e. White. It still shows my `body`'s  `background-color`. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE: To anyone interested I have found excellent ready-made CSS layouts at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C12/**

Comment: I'd suggest adding `#god_container { width: 1008px; }` to your css, that way the container element for your page respects the `width` (also, using `max-width` and `min-width` might be useful.

Comment: @david just tried it both `{width..` and `max-width:..` . Didn't work.

Comment: @Marcel, I *think* the intent is to center the background both vertically and horizontally (though if that's necessary with a `repeat-y` background is unknown).

Comment: @marcel as david said. the image is like a drop shadow. I want to have it vertically (on the left & right edges) of `div.root`. But this is what is not happening.

Comment: BTW, why did you put all those spaces in your CSS? Copy-pasting results in a horrible line wrapping here.

Comment: pardon if this question sounds basic, but very new to CSS & I was hoping the CSS gurus here could guide me. Why `width:1008px` in `#god_container` did not solve the problem? donno...

Comment: Can you show your complete page? I get a white background on my page, with a width of 1008 px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the `background-image` and color to the body, makes sure it is displayed on all pages, and have the `#god_container` act as a wrapper for the page, center it by `margin:0 auto;` and give it the `width:1008px;`.

Also you don't have to give the `position:static;` to the `#god_container` wrapping div, instead use `position:relative;` to make sure all child divs, are placed inside it even if positioned absolutely.

At last, giving `#root` a `width:100%` will place the div to it's parent div width.

Try using this CSS:

```
body{
  color:#373737;
  font:16px arial;
  line-height:1;
  background:url("/site_media/images/bg-1008.png") repeat-y scroll center center #D4D9DD;
}

#god_container{
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  width:1008px;
}

#root{
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  margin:auto;
  width:100%;
  color:#000000;
  font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
  font-size:10pt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm missing something here, but it could be much simpler. You don't need a wrapper DIV... the body can handle that. All you need is your root DIV.

**CSS**

```
body{
    background: #D4D9DD url("/site_media/images/bg-1008.png") repeat-y center;
    color:#373737;
    font: 16px/1 Arial;
}
#root {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1008px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        ... all content ...
    </div>
</body>
```

Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/XdA92/1/

Comment: or even better: remove root, us `<html>` for rendering your background and `<body>` for rendering the root.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

give the back ground url to the main body so that it will go to all pages

```
#god_container{                                                                                                       
        background:url("/site_media/images/bg-1008.png") repeat-y scroll center center #D4D9DD;                           
        margin:auto;                                                                                                      
        position:static;                                                                                                  
    text-align:left;
    width:1008px;                                                                                                   
    }
```

Comment: Reading the comments to his question reveals that he tried that. Though **why it didn't work** is unknown.

Comment: pardon if this question sounds basic, but very new to CSS & I was hoping the CSS gurus here could guide me. Why `width:1008px` in `#god_container` did not solve the problem? donno...